# Solution for Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have problem when decrypt in PHP on the web server, it's fail when I try to decyrpt my
   encryption that store in the database, the output of the decrypt show in symbol like this:
 
Â±8Â¼Â®Â¿2>~Ã«Â¥Ã™nÃ?

here is the code that I used for decrypt:
[encrypt/decrypt](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php)

```
<?php

class MCrypt
{
private $iv = 'fedcba9876543210'; 
private $key = '0123456789abcdef';

function_construct()
{
}


function decrypt($code)
{
    //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);
    $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
    $iv = $this->iv;

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
}

protected function hex2bin($hexdata)
{
    $bindata = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2)
    {
        $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
    }
    return $bindata;
}
}
?>
```

and here is the code I used to get the encrypt data from database:

```
include ("decrypt.php");

$sql     = "SELECT * FROM Save_data";

$mcrypt = new MCrypt();
#Decrypt
$decrypted1 = $mcrypt->decrypt($exif_datetime);
echo $decrypted1;
```

Comment: That output would indicate that your string's probably utf-8 data but being output in the wrong character set. The repeated `Â` characters are typical of this.

Comment: Try to get rid of the `utf8_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the encrypt method its impossible to say why the code is not behaving as you expect, however....

```
return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
```

Eh? This doesn't make any sense. Certainly if you need to change ISO-8859-1 to utf8 then this is how you'd go about it - but there is no way this should be done in the same method as the decryption.

> when I try to decyrpt my encryption that store in the database

Looking at the code it implies that the enrypted data is stored as binary. Really? For various reasons it makes a lot more sense to base64_encode (or convert to ascii HEX) the encrypted data before storing it in the DB (and hence base64_decode before decrypting).

Answer (score 0):

lets say if your output is `$txt = Â±8Â¼Â®Â¿2>~Ã«Â¥Ã™nÃ Loréane,`

you can solve this by below code

echo utf8_encode($txt);

Or try to add meta tag  `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Hope it helps.